# How to get MS SQL SERVER Database wise CPU usage report

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

I am using Sql Server 2008 Standard Edition in my PC. There is more than 30 databases are

running in my Server. I am try to generate a report based on database wise CPU usage

report. Is possible this report as graphical ?

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible but I’d try looking at some of the third party monitoring tools and trying to reverse engineer how its done.

[Red gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/) has a tool you can check out but I’m sure there are many others as well